# Updating or refreshing a Swift Widget for an IOS Quote App

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, widget, refresh

**Summary**: I'm trying to implement my first widget. My widget is connected to my Quote Swift Application which is where I pull the data/quotes from to display through my widget. I'm able to successfully sync my widget and my app. Meaning I can see a quote on the widget and when I click the widget it opens my app.

**Issue**: Unfortunately, my widget is not updating by itself. It only updates when I click the widget.

**Question:** What changes can I make to my code to allow my widget to refresh either every hour or at lease once a day?

Here is my code:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), text: "UpLifted", configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), text: "UpLifted", configuration: configuration)
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.QuotePackage") 
        let text = userDefaults?.value(forKey: "text") as? String ?? "No Text"
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
        
        let currentDate = Date()
       for hourOffset in 0 ..< 2 {
           let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry( date: entryDate, text: text, configuration: configuration)
            entries.append(entry)
            
        }
let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
                completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
   public let date: Date
   public let text: String
    public let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
}



struct QuoteWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
  
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        
            Text(entry.text)
                .font(Font.custom("Georgia", size: 20))
                .fontWeight(.light)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(6)
        }
    }
}

@main
struct QuoteWidget: Widget {
    public var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: "QuoteWidget",
                                   intent: ConfigurationIntent.self,
                                   provider: Provider()) { entry in
                   QuoteWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
               }
               .configurationDisplayName("UpLifted Quotes")
               .description("Get a dose of inspiration")
           }
        }

struct QuoteWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
        QuoteWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(
            date: Date(),
            text: "UpLifted",
            configuration: ConfigurationIntent()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this for your timeline

```swift
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 60, to: currentDate)!
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.QuotePackage") 
        let text = userDefaults?.value(forKey: "text") as? String ?? "No Text"
        let entry = SimpleEntry( date: entryDate, text: text, configuration: configuration)
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(entryDate))
        completion(timeline)
    
    }
```